# Sum of a Range with mixed data, which included A , A2.5

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula, excel-2007

I have a spreadsheet with where employees have taken Annual Day or Few hours of Annual Leave. I want to calculate the total amount of leave per week, month, etc.

Data in the spreadsheet includes A = Annual Leave S = Sick Leave.
if a cell is A or S then its a full day of leave 8Hrs.
if a Cell is A2.5 its only 2.5Hrs of annual leave.
[image]

I have used `=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(D2:I2,1)="A")*7.6)` convert the A to full day.
but have trouble converting A2.5 = 2.5

The expected result is if a Row contains A and A2.5 the total to be 10.1 (7.6+2.5)

Comment: so should A and S be caculated Separate or together?

Comment: A and S to be calculate seperately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat the cells containing whole days seperately.

Extract the hour form other cells using `MID` and use `--` to convert the resulting strings to numbers

```
=SUM(IF(D$2:I$2="A",7.6,IF(LEFT(D$2:I$2,1)="A",--MID(D$2:I$2,2,999),"")))
```

Comment: Thanks, work as expected and thank you for the explanation. That's best way to learn. I was stumped thinking left, right and mid can only handle one cell at a time. Out of curiosity is this possible with sumproduct?

Comment: @relik `SUMPRODUCT` works just the same in this case, just upate `SUM`to `SUMPRODUCT`